# React Router: Render new view without page refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router

[image: React Route Load Test]

Hello! What I'm trying to do is rework my react-router so the NavLink renders a completely new page on click, instead of rendering at the bottom of the div, as shown in the gif above.

Here's the content of my main App.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home.js';
import About from './About.js';
import September from './September.js';
import Trilogy from './Trilogy.js';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route path='/about/' component={About} />
            <Route path='/september/' component={September} />
            <Route exact path='/september/trilogy/' component={Trilogy} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

The Home component's code, which holds the NavBar that's used in the Home Page.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, NavLink, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from './logo.png';
import About from './About.js';
import September from './September.js';
import Trilogy from './Trilogy.js';

let NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="container2"><NavLink to='/about/'>About</NavLink> </h2>
      <img src={logo} className="somersetLogo" alt="somersetLogo" />
      <h2 className="container" ><a href="mailto:contact@somersetproductions.co" className="mailto">Contact</a></h2>
    </div>
  )
}

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <NavBar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/about/' component={About} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Any idea what went wrong? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is your react router version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using react router v4 or above it should be something like this.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Link to='/about'>
    About
</Link>
```

Why you are defining router again in `Home` component which is not needed. Keeping route configuration in `App` component would be enough. Hope this helps. Happy coding !

Comment: Appreciate the help! Unfortunately, the solution doesn't work. The Link seems to function exactly like the NavLink. The click is rendering the info in the same div, but not as another page. Is it possible to do a multi-page app with React Router or is what I'm asking to do not possible?

Comment: edit: I figured it out! The way you had it was right! I put the Link after the Switch component and got rid of the NavBar and it worked! Thanks a ton! @Ravindra Ranwala