# Can't get link to display a new page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I've been trying to use React Router to set up a page with a link on it, that will display a new page when a user clicks on the link.  I've tried a simplified version of the example in the [React Router documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic), but it displays additional page at the bottom of the existing page when the user clicks on a link, rather than displaying a new page.

I've found several StackOverflow questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306054/react-router-render-new-view-without-page-refresh), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923128/react-router-render-component-on-same-page), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48838413/how-to-navigate-to-a-new-page-react-router-v4)) that seem similar, but I haven't found a solution there--it appears that some people have gotten it to work, but they don't post the complete code and I haven't been able to guess correctly what they've done.  A couple places seem to suggest that the `<Route>` has to be in a different file in order to get a new page to show up.  Based on that, here is my latest attempt:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App.js';
import About from './About.js';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers: ...
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <h1>This is the main page</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <hr />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**About.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';

function About() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default About;
```

If I click on the link, the URL bar shows that it's bringing up localhost:3000/about.  But the page doesn't change.  If I refresh the browser, it then redisplays "About" on its own page, which is what I want it to do when I click on the link.  That's the closest I've come, but how do I get it to do the right thing without needing a refresh?  Or is there something else I'm doing totally wrong?

The react-router-dom version is 4.3.1.  I'm using Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the second `<Router>` component in App.js. That causes the issue.

> A  that uses the HTML5 history API (pushState, replaceState
>   and the popstate event) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.

[Source](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)

[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wo6r6wvj8)

Comment: There's only one `<Router>` element in App.js.  So I don't know what you mean.  It might be better to post a complete code example (at least for one file, or one class or function).  I have already seen several answers with incomplete information and have been unsuccessful at guessing what I'm really supposed to do.

Comment: you have one Router component in the `index.js` and one in `app.js` not sure if you updated your code recenty or it is different with the code in the question, sandbox coming in

Comment: OK, I see.  But earlier, when I tried something like this, it complained that a <Link> should be inside a <Router>.  I don't remember what my exact sources were.  Why isn't it complaining now?

Comment: it isn't complaining because components passed to the `Route` component are under the root `Router` component